# Why did Count Dooku call them swords instead of lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

When facing Obi-wan and Anakin, Count Dooku said:

> Your swords, please. We don't want to make a mess of things in front
>   of the Chancellor.

Wasn't it called a “lightsaber”? Why did he say “sword” instead? It seems like saying “your spears please” when asking for Jango Fett’s blaster pistols, or "Your eggs, please" for a thermal detonator.

Maybe it was just a slip of the tongue of him with a sudden specter?

Comment: ["A lightsaber is a fictional energy **sword**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightsaber). ["The lightsaber, sometimes referred to as a laser **sword**"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber). Even common English: ["The sabre or saber (see spelling differences) is a type of back**sword**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabre) Or check this: http://www.marlowwhite.com/military-sword-information/m-us-army-sword.html

Comment: Okay, why was this so heavily DV'd? I see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @DBPriGuy Sometimes questions will get downvoted for being stupid questions. A lightsaber is clearly a sword. You could put that under "research effort" if you like. Looking up what a 'sword' is would solve this pretty quickly.

Comment: I always thought that the term lightsaber is more a of a "slang" term rather than what they are. They are neither sabers (curved blade, single edged, single handed) nor are they made of light. I always thought that some person called it a lightsaber and the name just stuck. I imagined that is how it happend out of universe as George Lucas always calls them Laserswords (again, technically the blade is not a laser).

Comment: I think it's a fair question. I don't remember anyone else using sword in Star Wars so why did Dooku use it but no one else?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because a lightsaber is of a class of weapons known as "swords."

Similarly, one would ask where to park one’s car rather than one’s Porsche.

Or "look after my horse" rather than "look after my Arabian Destrier." [note that I haven't a clue about horses so please forgive me if destriers don't come from Arabian stock or whatever].

Police officers will cry out "He's got a gun!" And nobody replies "Yea, but is it a 9 mm? Is it semi-automatic, fully automatic, bolt action, matchlock? C'mon officer, we can't possibly respond appropriately without these details!"

Answer (score 3):

A lightsaber is just another name for an energy sword. Young Anakin also called it a "laser sword" in *The Phantom Menace*.